# Is there any reason to upgrade from FreeBSD 6.x?

Tags: freebsd

I currently run FreeBSD 6.x, and everything is running smoothly. Is there any reason for me to upgrade to 7 or 8 when it comes out? Am I missing any hot new feature, that I would just have to have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that I can think off from the top of my head, but you could always read these:

- http://www.freebsd.org/releases/7.0R/announce.html
- http://www.freebsd.org/releases/7.1R/announce.html
- http://www.freebsd.org/releases/7.2R/announce.html

Edit: Now I remember. It has a very improved scheduler set by default (from 7.1 and up), wich increases SMP performance dramatically.

Comment: Yes: SCHED_ULE is much higher performance. All of my systems are 7.2 now, and the benchmarked performance with SCHED_ULE is better, by far.

Answer (score 1):

If you use jails support will be improved in 7.2 and 8.0 allowing better network access.

Answer (score 1):

ZFS is pretty hot.